# How do you import ngTagsInput into your project with AngularJS and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm-install

How do you prevent this message while trying to use ngTagsInput? I tried to go to the module and put in:

```
var app = angular.module("SinglePageApplication", [ "ngRoute",  'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTagsInput']);
```

However, this always throws the following error below.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module SinglePageApplication due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngTagsInput due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngTagsInput' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ngTagsInput
```

Additionally, I trying to install it, using this [link](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/download) and calling the command:

```
$ npm install ng-tags-input@3.1.1 --save
```

But this always throws the error:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@1.0.1
└── ng-tags-input@3.1.1
```

All I want is to be able to use the tags-input, however I feel I am missing something major to have all of these issue. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember running into an issue with this and the fix/workaround I came up with was to copy the `ng-tags-input.js` locally and keep it within .git.

I had totally forgotten to check up on this, at the time there was a bug with any Angular >= 1.5. Can't recall the bug exactly but I think my issue was when hitting enter it would select one of items from the dropdown rather than submitting the input.